# Reason for The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, t-sql

error - The multi-part identifier "Grant.EmpID" could not be bound.

query -

```
select emp.EmpID, 
COUNT(*) as CountRecords,
COUNT(GrantName) AS CountValues
From Employee as emp full join [Grant] as gr
on emp.EmpID = [Grant].EmpID 
-- This is the cause for the error ! Change it to gr.EmpID
group by emp.EmpID
```

Why does this error occur ? Can't I call a person by real name and also by nickname ?

Comment: what rdbms you are using? and the version of it?

Comment: @JW. - sql server 2008 express

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're aliasing `[Grant]`. In other words, you're stating that from here on out, `[Grant]` will be referred to as `gr`.

Use the `ALIAS` in the `GROUP BY` clause, not the tableName.

```
SELECT emp.EmpID, 
       COUNT(*) as CountRecords,
       COUNT(GrantName) AS CountValues
FROM   Employee as emp 
       FULL JOIN [Grant] as gr
          on emp.EmpID = gr.EmpID  -- use the alias.
GROUP BY gr.EmpID                  -- use the alias.
```

here's the SQL Order of Operation

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

No you can't because sql server is not a human. imagine we have an Employee table which references itself

```
select * 
from Employee Emp, Employee Mng
where Emp.ManagerID = Mng.EmployeeID
```

Mng and Emp are two instances of Employee

so if I select

```
select * from Employee e, Employee
```

it will return all employee TWO times, because I am telling give me employees once under the name `Employee` once under the name `e` (alias)